# React-Native TypeORM: Cyclic dependency “t” Android Release build

Tags: react-native-sqlite-storage

how do you resolve this problem?
React-Native TypeORM: Cyclic dependency “t” Android Release build

Answer (score 0):

Getting typeorm to work with react native is tricky. For me the only solution was to disable minification. On android:

> **Go to** :  android/app/build.gradle

Edit the following:

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    extraPackagerArgs: [ '--minify=false' ], 
]
```